# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}' SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, f-string

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
from flask_login import LoginManager

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "YouDontGetTheKey"
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix="/")
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix="/")

    from .models import User, Post, Comment, Like

    create_database(app)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = "auth.login"
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))

    return app


def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists("website/" + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print("Created database!")
```

I Get A Syntax Error on Line 13:

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'

Its on the last ' and I dont know how to fix this

(This is from a TechWithTim tutorial) I have looked over my code and compared that line to the og & it works for TechWithTim but not me. I am using the glitch.com website so I don't know if its just that website or an error in my code

Comment: can you edit and paste the full error log here

Comment: I have python3 but I am using the glitch.com website.

Comment: You can go and see the logs by pressing tools then logs at this area: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/cks-blogs-?path=website%2F__init__.py%3A1%3A0

Comment: this is the error though:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   File "/app/website/__init__.py", line 13 
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
                                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Just use `'sqlite:///' + DB_NAME`

Comment: Ok, Ill try that

Comment: There's no Syntax Error that's obvious in your code. Have you made sure that all your quotes (`"` and `'`) are the correct characters, i.e. not some weird Unicode versions?

Comment: Thank you OneCricketeer, that works

Comment: f-strings are only supported on Python3.6+. Are you sure that is the case for you?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if its 3.6 or above since the website I was using is mainly meant for html, css, and js not python but it's free and has it so I just try and use it